# How to use axios in a separated class

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, axios

I'm new in react and what i'm trying to do is a proxy pattern with axios ouside my component "home" but when i put axios in my separated class it doesn't work. But it works inside my component
Here's my proxy class:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default class daniProxy {

  constructor(proxyUrl, apiUrl) {
    this.proxyUrl = proxyUrl;
    this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
  }

  getDanis(restUrt) {
    let ds = {};
    axios
      .get(this.proxyUrl + this.apiUrl + restUrt)
      .then((danis) => {
        ds = {
          data: danis.data,
        };
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    return ds;
  }
}
```

And here is my home component class:

```
class home extends Component {
  state = {
    danis: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let prox = new daniProxy(proxyurl,apiurl);
    console.log(prox.getDanis('/getDanis'))
  }
```

any idea why it doesn't return something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the GET request is asychronous so the return execute before. You should catch the promise.

```
  getDanis(restUrt) {
    return axios
      .get(this.proxyUrl + this.apiUrl + restUrt)
      .then((danis) => {
        return {
          data: danis.data,
        };
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Then, in your component you can get the result

```
componentDidMount() {
    let prox = new daniProxy(proxyurl,apiurl);
    prox.getDanis('/getDanis').then((res) => {
       console.log(res);     
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

your `return ds` statement wont wait axios promise to be resolved. once you call axios, next line is evaluated right away and `ds` is still an empty object. instead, try returning the promise:

```
  getDanis(restUrt) {
    return axios
      .get(this.proxyUrl + this.apiUrl + restUrt)
      .then((danis) => {
        return {
          data: danis.data,
        };
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

now at your componentDidMount you may declare as async and do:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    let prox = new daniProxy(proxyurl,apiurl);
    const result = await prox.getDanis('/getDanis');
    console.log(result);
  }
```

or chain your promise:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let prox = new daniProxy(proxyurl,apiurl);
    prox.getDanis('/getDanis')
        .then(console.log);        
  }
```